# MIssing the last step to map Json to a List/Array (Flutter)

Tags: json, flutter

I'm new to the Flutter (Dart) environment, so looking for some guidance on what I hope is a trivial coding issue on my side.

**I have** the following json, which I've validated,.....

```
[{"refModel":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","os":"121212","refStatus":"Y","refActivationDate":"0000-00-00","gamesMiddles":0,"middles":[],"gamesLines":0,"lines":[],"gamesToReport":0,"reports":[]}]}]
```

**The** following is the class structure I use (not final version, needs further definitions).....
[image]

**Data looks** good after using json.decode (see below)
[image]

**but when** trying to map the data to the defined class, RefProfile, using the following....

```
setState(() {
  refProfile = RefProfile.fromJson(refMap);
});
```

with following code generated by json_annotation.dart

[image]

**the resulting refProfile.refModel list(array)** contains 1 record but all fields are null.
I've been reworking the code based on reading stackoverflow and googling for suggestions for the past 3 days but no luck, so any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you have nested models i think you need `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)` instead of `@JsonSerializable()`. See the docs here : https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/explicitToJson.html - "If true, generated toJson methods will explicitly call toJson on nested objects."

Comment: thxs for the speedy reply Shannon, but the suggested change didn't help.  Also thxs for the link, I will go thru the docs you provided to see if that can guide me to the right answer.

Comment: Did you build your files agian -  `pub run build_runner build` also make sure you are using fresh data if this is coming from shared preferences or a file.

Comment: yes I did. Even delete the "_g_" file to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

as suspected, coding issue on my side.  To make this work, I changed 
refProfile = RefProfile.fromJson(refMap); 
to 
refProfile = RefProfile.fromJson(refMap['refModel']); 
so the mapping script now properly finds the json object and maps the api data to the local model.